# Regex constraint on string type in thrift

Tags: thrift

Is there a way that one can put a regex constraint on string field in struct in Thrift IDL? Eg. I wanted to make a restriction on one field which is string that its value should have some particular prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Restrictions are supposed to be handled in the application logic.